# How to install Dropbox SDK

Tags: python, dropbox

here https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/python im download SDK and then try to run setup code on windows server 2008 like this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyth
on36-32\python.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dropbox-python-sdk-2.2.0\setup
.py install
```

and then got this in console:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dropbox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dropbox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to dropbox.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to dropbox.egg-info\top_level.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

package init file 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36
-32/dropbox\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36
-32/tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dropbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'dropbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install


creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying dropbox.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying dropbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying dropbox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying dropbox.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying dropbox.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it

removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg
Removing c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\si
te-packages\dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg
Copying dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg to c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs
\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
dropbox 2.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\s
ite-packages\dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for dropbox==2.2.0
Searching for urllib3==1.21.1
Best match: urllib3 1.21.1
Processing urllib3-1.21.1-py3.6.egg
urllib3 1.21.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\urllib3-1.21.1-py3.6.egg
Finished processing dependencies for dropbox==2.2.0
```

and nothing happened, folders "dropbox" and "tests" still empty
whats wrong?

Comment: Well, can you import the dropbox module in a script, or not?

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont know, just nothing happens after im run setup. Or what are you talking about?

Comment: It installed the package in `c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages` where the python libraries are. This folder should be in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, and therefore you should be able to import the library with `import dropbox`.

Comment: @Paco H my `site-packag‌​es` folder contain `dropbox-2.2.0-py3.6.egg`. Is that what im looking for? And what is `import dropbox`? Is that another command? "Import the library" in google given me nothing. And so, SDK's instruction said what i have to just run setup and its it. Why its not working that way?

Comment: @Diskyp Yes, the instructions are correct, you run setup and install the library in the path I't mentions in the logs. If you go to the [next part of the tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python) you see that the first statement is the `import dropbox` which loads the dropbox package you just installed with `setup.py install`.

Comment: @Paco H oh sorry, now i catched it. I add folder what you says to PYTHONPATH variable and try to run this code: try: from dropbox import client, rest, session except ImportError: print "Need Dropbox!" sys.exit(1) So, it says what i need dropbox

Comment: You are running a `try-except` statement. Just `import dropbox`... Did it work, or not?

Comment: @cricket_007 at least i didnt got any errors but also nothing happens after i run just `import dropbox`

Comment: By the way, you've been linking to the old/deprecated version of the Dropbox Python SDK. Make sure you follow the latest instructions here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python

Comment: That means it installed! Congrats :)

Comment: @cricket_007 huh, its installed but doesnt work. Anyway, i guess its need to be in another question.

Comment: @Greg thanks for link